# SVG-React Component for Typescript

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, svg

Is there any way to convert a SVG into a react component with typescript and webpack? I know SVGs can be displayed with the `<img>`-Tag, but as I want to change color with CSS this is not sufficient enough.

I tried several svg-components for react, but those are not working with typescript as they are not of a specific type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SVG-React Component for Typescript

Just return `svg` content from your render function.

Example:

```
export class Mail extends React.PureComponent<{}, {}>{
  render() {
    return (
      <svg width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 25 25">
        <g stroke="none" strokeWidth={1} fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
          <g fill="#807370">
            <g transform="translate(3.000000, 6.000000)">
              <path d="M11.541,7.064 C11.006,7.439 10.219,7.662 9.433,7.662 L9.418,7.662 C8.629,7.662 7.842,7.437 7.307,7.062 L0,2 L0,11.474 C0,11.885 0.334,12.22 0.746,12.22 L17.869,12.22 C18.277,12.22 18.613,11.885 18.613,11.474 L18.613,2.166 L11.541,7.064" />
              <path d="M8.086,6.549 C8.396,6.768 8.916,6.905 9.422,6.905 L9.432,6.905 C9.934,6.905 10.457,6.766 10.766,6.551 L18.613,1.111 L18.613,0.746 C18.613,0.334 18.277,0 17.869,0 L0.746,0 C0.334,0 0,0.334 0,0.746 L0,0.945 L8.086,6.549" />
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
    );
  }
}
```

## More

- https://egghead.io/lessons/react-render-basic-svg-components-in-react

Comment: I have found this solution as well, but it is inconvenient as not all SVG-types are compatible with typescript (inkscape SVGs for example contain information which is unreadable by the typescript compiler). Is there another way?

Comment: this is the way. Use `any` to silence any type errors, its just like using raw JavaScript 

Comment: @basarat Using ```any``` for silencing errors in Typescript negates sense of using that language at all.

In this case it would make more sense to check SVG-types with list in this file: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts

Follow types in interface: ```SVGAttributes```